# How use aliases in Angular 8?

Tags: alias, angular8

I try to use aliases in Angular 8 but doesn't work. Weird, it seems to be so simple. I probably miss something. First, I tried it with environnement import.

*./src/environments/environment.ts*

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/"
};
```

*./tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "paths": {
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    },
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

./src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env/environment'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myapp : ' + environment.apiUrl ;
}
```

Here error I have

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@env/environment' in 'C:\www\node\skeleton\src\app'
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure your paths are pointing correctly , like this, **dots included!!**

```
{
 "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["./src/environments/*"]
  }
}
```